# Java Load Balancing Options

Tags: apache, glassfish, load-balancing

Rather than reinvent the wheel, I'd like to utilize an open source load balancer for my Java backend. I'll be using GlassFish as the app server (running an `EAR`), and each app server will most likely be running on an Ubuntu Server VM.

[image]

So the load balancer will *probably* (although I'm open for other ideas!) be its own Ubuntu Server VM running some sort of open source load balancing software. As to what this is (please note the big "`?`" in the diagram!) I don't really care so long as it:

- Is super fast
- Is secure
- Plays nice with GlassFish
- Is free and open source and comes with a license that doesn't restrict me from selling this system as a product or service
- Is *relatively* easy to configure (but I'm not scared do get my hands dirty)

Just wondering what my (best) options were. So far I've scouted out:

- Apache `HTTPd`
- haproxy
- nginx

But nothing is blowing my doors down as being the end-all-be-all-obvious-solution to my requirements. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or nudges in the right direction!

Comment: What is it you're balancing... http requests, session beans, etc...

Comment: HTTP and HTTPS, as for beans I've got a different solution altogether. Just looking for the right software/hardware technology to balance incoming (external) HTTP/S requests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition supports AJP (mod_jk, mod_proxy, see the administration guide in the [all-in-one docs bundle](http://download.java.net/glassfish/3.1.1/release/glassfish-ose-3.1.1-docs-pdf.zip)). Oracle GlassFish Server ships with a plugin that works with Apache httpd, IIS, and the Oracle iPlanet Web Server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks John! So it's possible to have a "load balancer" server that might be running Apache/AJP and then have it working with each of the different app servers that sit behind it?

Comment: FYI: About GlassFish network topologies and load-balancing: http://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/about_glassfish_network_topologies_and

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete overview about what comes out-of-the-box and is commonly used.
http://blog.eisele.net/2012/01/throwing-light-on-glassfish-webserver.html
In commercial scenarios I have seen a lot of BigIP products in use.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Python Director](http://pythondirector.sourceforge.net/) in the past with great success. This isn't really a Java problem, any SLB ( Software Load Balancer ) will do the job to load balance and proxy HTTP.

We actually hacked ZeroConf / Bonjour into our version of Python Director so that the load balancer would auto discover when things were added or removed from the network automatically.
It worked in production for a couple of years with no issues, we never had to touch it.